# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

> CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 1s

> Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: C:\Users...gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\android.jar\637e2bccbff6bd0f7a7583f7e9d4551b\android.jar with input C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar

> Gradle sync failed: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, returnDefaultValues=false} using transform MockableJarTransform

> Cannot create mockable android.jar
> zip file is empty

I am new to android studio. I have tried all the answers I could get none worked.
I changed my gradle plugin to 3.1.1 and lower is still the same thing.
I have clean build and invalidate cache/reset.

Do I have to install a lower android studio. Why is this happening for a new project?
Andriod studio 3.2.1

Comment: I found the source of the problem. I noticed that the andriod.jar file in C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28 was missing, the file was 0kb. which shouldn't be so. So I reinstalled the Android SDK platform and sources by uninstalling it from SDK Manager and installed it back. then the problem was solved.

Answer (score 31):

@Openwell  thanks  a  lot.   you  save my  day!

I found the source of the problem. I noticed that the andriod.jar file in C:\Users**\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28 was missing, the file was 0kb. which shouldn't be so. So I reinstalled the Android SDK platform and sources by uninstalling it from SDK Manager and installed it back. then the problem was solved.

Comment: Saved my further time. Was going mad around this. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 6):

I just changed the compiled version to API level to which I have downloaded in the SDK Manager. For me in File=>Project Structure, the compiled version is set to 29 which I haven't downloaded SDK. So I changed it to 28 which I have downloaded.Then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

for mac users go to Users/***/Library/Android/sdk/platforms and then delete all the platform, and run the application. This works for me.

Comment: Deleting all the platforms also worked for me on Windows.
Even though my sdk matched the compile version, on reloading Android Studio, it redownloaded everything and worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading AndroidStudio version to 4.1, also upgraded Android Gradle plugin to 4.1.0.

But in Project root folder build.gradle file, In dependencies, it has this below gradle classpath for com.google.gms:google-services version as 4.3.0. Caused the issue.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
```

after upgrading com.google.gms:google-services to latest version, and Sync project.

```
dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        }
```

Solved the issue.