# Problem ouccuring in sync in android studio : Not able to build any new project

Tags: java, android

Error 1: Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, returnDefaultValues=false}

Error 2 : Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create mockable android.jar

Comment: file->invalidate caches/restart

Comment: Can you also reformat the question and add details?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the same issue: Your `android-xx` directory is surely corrupted even though the SDK Manager saw it downloaded.

The fix is to delete your installation via the SDK Manager and to download it again.

Delete & re-download those one:

[image: Remove and download]

Also what the corrupted installation looked like (in this case `android-34`) :

[image: Corrupted dir]

[Related Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648319/could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration-appandroidapis)